# Node.js - asynchronous method call issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, methods

I am building an app using node.js and wanted to confirm an issue regarding modules and node's asynchronous nature. If I have a module such as:

```
var email_list = function() {
    //perform some database query or calculation
}

exports.email_to = function() {

    email_list.forEach(function(email) {
        console.log(email);
    });

};
```

And in another file, I call my `email_to` method, does the function`email_list` get called before my `email_to` function gets called? If not, is there a way to guarantee that the `email_to` function gets called after the `email_list` function?

Thanks in advance~

Comment: Your email_list function is not going to work the way you expect since it contains a promise

Comment: thanks - i just edited it to make it more generic

Comment: There are no calls to the `email_list` function in your code, so no, it wouldn't be called before `email_to`. Functions are only called when you call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented, but I'll elaborate a little bit.  Your going to want to do something like this:

```
var email_list = function() {

    return knex('email_list').where({
            verified: true
        });    
};

exports.email_to = function() {

    var response = email_list()
        .then(function(emailList){
            emailList.forEach(function(email){
                console.log(email);
            });
        });
};
```

There is a lot of documentation out there about the event lifecycle of Node and Javascript in general.  On a really high level, you are going to want to study how promises and callbacks work.  That is how you "guarantee" things get called when you would expect them to.

In this case, *email_list* returns a promise.  You can use the result of that promise in your *email_to* function.  You wait for the result of that promise by using *then*

Comment: Super high level.  I hope this didn't make your question more confusing.